# Error Couldn't add script to package.json: Error: spawn npm ENOENT

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, package.json, webdriver-io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWpLW.png)When i am running script in webdriver.io using visual studio node.js this error is generated. Couldn't add script to package.json: Error: spawn npm ENOENT

I have tried many solution like npm cache clear , deleting the package.json file along with node modules and reinstall npm but issue not resolved

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error as well when trying to set up webdriverio.

Doing npm init wdio. Once I configure everything, error after it tries to do npm install

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please use "Comment" feature to enrich the question but avoid "fake" answer.